# JQuery Accordion Conflicting with Tree Stucture

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, accordion

On a previous website, I had an EasyUI Tree Structure embedded within a JQuery Accordion. At this point in time, the scripts seem to be conflicting. Before the EasyUI Script is included, the accordion functions as needed. As soon as the script is included, though, the accordion structure breaks. Any ideas?

Accordion Script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  heightStyle: "content"
});
});
</script>
```

EasyUI Script:

```
<script src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"> </script>
```

Also note that if the Accordion script is removed, the Tree Structure works perfectly. Somehow these scripts are conflicting with one another, but I did not have this issue on my previous site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, it happens, because jquery ui and easy ui include accordion plugin. So if you want to use the accordion of jquery ui, you must disable the accordion of easyui.

Comment: Oh, great idea. How would I disable EasyUI's accordion?

Comment: I think the best way to solve it - to rename plugin name

Comment: Well I need the tree structure from Easy UI. Is there anyway I can just disable the Accordion Function of EasyUI and just use JQuery's Accordion, then EasyUI's tree separately?

Comment: You can rename EasyUI accordion to ,for example accordion1, but in this case, you will have to connect EasyUI from your server

Comment: THe EasyUI Accordion code is embedded within the entire EasyUI script, where the tree code is also located.

Comment: To remove EasyUI accordion you should remove it from array of plugins in EasyUI file (for example - http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js). This array starts as: `plugins:["draggable","droppable",...]`

Comment: I actually deleted it from that array, but the problem is still here.

Comment: Also try replacing all occurrences of `$.fn.accordion` on `$.fn.accordion1` in EasyUI file

Comment: YOU GOT IT! Thanks man! That has been bugging me for hours, couldnt find the kink. I appreciate your help more than you can imagine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54649/discussion-between-stmyd-and-yaroslav-osetrov).